# how to create right to left grid layout nativescript

Tags: layout, nativescript, grid-layout

I want to create a right to left grid layout in nativescript I search a whole day hoping to find a solution but I couldn't find any so here is what I want, consider this sample gridlayout:

```
<GridLayout columns="*,*,*" rows="*,*,*,*,*"  sdkExampleTitle sdkToggleNavButton>
    <Button text="1" row="0" col="0" style="background-color: #0099CC; margin: 5;"></Button>
    <Button text="2" row="0" col="1" style="background-color: #FFFF66; margin: 5;"></Button>
    <Button text="3" row="0" col="2" style="background-color: #AA0078; margin: 5;"></Button>
    <Button text="4" row="1" col="0" style="background-color: #8C489F; margin: 5;"></Button>
    <Button text="5" row="1" col="1" style="background-color: #CCFFFF; margin: 5;"></Button>
    <Button text="6" row="1" col="2" style="background-color: #0099CC; margin: 5;"></Button>
</GridLayout>
```

As you see this is a grid layout with 2 row and 3 columns

[image]

As you can see in the above picture content aligned from left to right. Know I want to change this layout to achieve the right to left alignment like the below picture, how can I do this with gridlayout I test horizontal alignment and set it to right but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: Why isn't changing the rows/columns numbers good enough?
Does it need to support multiple languages?

Comment: imagine I have 2 columns in the first row changing row and columns number won't solve the problem because I want the empty space for 3 columns to be in the left side not right

Comment: few questions: 1. Will you always have up to 6 shapes on screen? 2. If shape #5 is missing, will shape #6 be missing (in the second picture)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridLayout is all about how you setup the rows / columns, to get expected results in the screenshot you may have to manually reverse the col value you are assigning.

Or you may use [FlexboxLayout](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=laS8r9) which might give you same results, minor styling tweaks may be required still.

Comment: imagine I have 2 columns in the first row changing row and columns value won't solve the problem because I want the empty space for 3 columns to be in the left side not right.So there is no solution to tackle this problem with gridlayout?

Comment: That should still solve the problem, if you don't assign component to be loaded within that particular column it will be empty. If you still have any issues, try creating a playground example and may be attach a screenshot of what should be the expected output, that might help us to understand exactly what you are looking for.